# Why does my set state does not get updated when given a value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parceljs

I was working with an api meaning that I fetch the api and convert it to json before i pass it to one of the state i want to update.

It was working fine until it didn't.

```
const [ids, setIDs] = useState([]);
```

This is the code for fetching from the api

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      //setting up the video ids
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/videosid");
      const jsonRes = await res.json();
      setIDs(jsonRes);
      //setting up the local database
      console.log("Fetching data from youtube...");

      console.log("ids:", ids);
      localStorage.setItem("VideosID", ids);
    };
```

when I console.log the values of res and jsonRes everything shows up, but for some reason it does not update the state.

Any ideas why ?

EDIT

I would also like to say that when doing the same with a local json file the state updates immediately.

```
const localfetchData = () => {
      //setting up the video ids
      setIDs(jsonfile);
      //setting up the local database
      localStorage.setItem("VideosID", ids);
    };
```

Comment: setState is **asynchronous**

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an asyncronous function so sometimes it takes time to update the state. So one solution you can try is `console logging` the values and setting it in `localStorage` after the function call.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  //setting up the video ids
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/videosid");
  const jsonRes = await res.json();
  setIDs(jsonRes);
  //setting up the local database
  console.log("Fetching data from youtube...");
};

fetchData()
console.log("ids:", ids);
localStorage.setItem("VideosID", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. So if  you need to ensure ordering of events after a setState call is made, you can pass a callback function

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      //setting up the video ids
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/videosid");
      const jsonRes = await res.json();
      setIDs(jsonRes, () => { 
                               console.log("ids:", ids);
                               localStorage.setItem("VideosID", ids);
                            });
     
       };
```

Or you can add `useEffect` function with a dependency on state.

```
 useEffect(() =>
 {
     console.log("ids:", ids);
     localStorage.setItem("VideosID", ids);
 }, [ids]);

 const fetchData = async () => {
  //setting up the video ids
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/videosid");
  const jsonRes = await res.json();
  setIDs(jsonRes);

 };
```